# How to send a form back a step in a multistep Webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically boot a user back to an earlier step if they fail validation or submission on one of the final steps of a form. The form has to check some remote service calls before accepting the submission.

I tried to add a validate hook and try something simple:

```
function mymodule_schedule_validate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $page = $form_state->get('current_page');

  if ($page == 'step_2') {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('tour_date', 'Pick some other thing or whatever');
    $form_state->set('current_page', 'step_1');
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    #$form_state->setRedirect(new RedirectResponse(\Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput('/form/schedule')->getRouteName()));
  }
}
```

While the code is hit when step 2 is submitted, and it sets current page to step_1, nothing else happens. The error appears, but the form displayed in the modal is still step 2. I tried with and without the redirect.

How can I manipulate the form this way?

Comment: If you haven't already seen this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-skip-pages-in-wizard-forms this is to skip steps but maybe that works in the other direction too

Comment: I tried that, but let me try again. I was able to see the current_step change in the form state, but the form would just reload on the same step.

Comment: Ah okay, moving it to a submit handler will let me do that - but I can't set form errors or prevent submission of the webform on the final step